# Fancybox manter seta anterior e próximo sempre visível

Tags: css, fancybox

Em meu site estou usando o fancyBox para mostrar imagem de um produto, está funcionando certo, mas preciso deixar as setas "Anterior" e "Próximo" sempre visíveis para deixar mais claro ao usuário que existe uma navegação, não possuo conhecimento suficiente para tal feito.

Em meu site estou usando esse FancyBox: [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

As referências que encontrei para uma tentativa de mudança, são essas:

```
.fancybox-prev, .fancybox-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent url('../../images/fancybox/blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
    z-index: 1003;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: 0;    
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -9999px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1003;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
    background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
    background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-prev:hover, .fancybox-next:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-prev:hover span {
    left: 20px;
}

.fancybox-next:hover span {
    left: auto;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Existem 'n' projetos com nome FancyBox ou similares, qual você está usando? [Edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/51923/edit) a pergunta e inclua alguma referência.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar isso ao seu css:

```
 .fancybox-next span {
    left: auto;
    right: 20px;
 }
 .fancybox-prev span {
    left: 20px;
 }
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8672001)

Comment: Olá @Andre Ribeiro, fiz a alteração indicada, mas não aconteceu nada.

Comment: Olá @Andre Ribeiro, consegui resolver, muito obrigado pela excelente dica novamente, fiz exatamente como indicado.